# iPhone simulator doesn't connect to the Internet. How should I set plist.info file?

Tags: xcode, http, ios-simulator, wifi

I have an iPhone simulator that should be using the Wi-Fi of the computer, but something in the http settings is not letting it.

During debugging I am seeing this error message:

```
App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
```

Here is my plist.info file. Any ideas on what to change in order to have Internet connection?

[image]

EDIT:

I saw somewhere online that adding this code solves the problem:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
     <dict>
          <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
     </dict>
```

But how do I add xml to that file? I don't see that setting. Here is where I saw it: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3544